# Custom BlockJUnit4ClassRunner which runs test suite set number of times

Tags: java, junit, annotations

I made the following custom [BlockJUnit4ClassRunner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html)

```
  public class RepeatEachTest extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

  private int repeats;

  public RepeatEachTest(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
    super(klass);
    Repeat r = klass.getAnnotation(Repeat.class);
    if (r == null) {
        throw new InitializationError("A @Repeat annonation must also be suplied to class, for example @Repeat(5) to repeat 5 times");
    }
    repeats = r.value();
  }

  @Override
  protected void runChild(FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) {
    for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++) {
        super.runChild(method, notifier);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int testCount() {
    return repeats * super.testCount();
  }
}
```

and

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Repeat {  
 int value();
}
```

to execute *each* test `@Repeat.value()` number of times. A test run of

```
@RunWith(RepeatEachTest.class)
@Repeat(2)
public class RepeatEachTestTest {

  @Test
  public void first() {
    System.out.println("ran first");
  }

  @Test
  public void second() {
    System.out.println("ran second");
  }
}
```

looks like

```
ran first
ran first
ran second
ran second
```

but now I want to implement a second [BlockJUnit4ClassRunner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html) which runs *the whole test class* `@Repeat.value()` number of times. A run from that setup would look like

```
ran first
ran second
ran first
ran second
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you want. If you want the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` methods and class rules to be called multiple times, you can override `classBlock()`:

```
protected Statement classBlock(final RunNotifier notifier) {
  return new Statement() {
    @Override
    public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
      for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++) {
        super.classBlock(notifier).evaluate();
      }
    }
  };
}
```

If you want the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` methods and class rules to be called once, override `childrenInvoker()` (the code would be similar).

Note, however, that either of these will result in the listeners being notified multiple times that the test has started and completed. Some listeners may not behave correctly in this situation.

Comment: Works like a charm! Hmm I could probably write a test runner that runs all tests for a predetermined time and then stops... Pretty cool